# JSON matching data and using data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've only every used json to fetch data to use on pages or set as variables. But now I would like to search json for a matching `name` then fetch its `views` from the json

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Pale","description":"This is a description","url":"http://domain.com//1/pale","views":2212,"createdBy":{"name":"Bill Lumbergh","url":"http://domain.com"},"createdOn":"2013-10-24T22:54:34.183"},
```

Above is a little example and using the below code only console.logs the entire json which has about 20 id's

```
$.getJSON( "content.php", { name: 'Pale' } ,function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'content.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(k,v){
                if (v.name == theme){
                    console.log(v.views);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Object you put in the code is the one you are passing to the Server, not receiving. `{name:'Pale'}` is being sent to the server. If you want the `name` from the JSON file, it's like:

```
$.getJSON('content.php', function(data){
  console.log(data.name);
});
```

However, if my guess is correct try the following:

```
$.getJSON('content.php', function(data){
  var ary = data.arrayThatHoldsYourObjects, store;
  $.each(ary, function(i, v){
    if(v.name === 'Pale'){
      store = v.views;
    }
  });
});
```

`store` now holds `v.views`.

Comment: `data` is the entire JSON Object. If there are multiple names then you need the attribute that contains the Array of Objects, then you need to loop over the Array looking for the `name`.